# How can I get an Input from a User with using CPUlator in ARM Assembly language

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7

I am currently working on a new project. I need to get input from the user. How can I get input from the user using ARM assembly language in CPUlator?

The work I have done so far is as follows

```
.global _start
 _start:

LDR R11, =0xFF200100  // buttons adress
LDR R6, [R11] //adress to buttons for get value



 end: B end
 .end
```

CPUlator link: https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm-de1soc

Any help will be very helpful, Thank you.

Comment: What kind of input? Text? Numbers? Button pushes? Spoken word?

Comment: The value I get from the user must be a number.

Comment: the value itself in a register?  an ascii string?

Comment: *...please  say spoken word...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're on the right track. The pushbuttons of CPUlator correspond to the bits in the word in memory at the fixed address of 0xFF200050. So the following will read the word into the `r0` register:

```
ldr r0, =0xFF200050  //Load the address into a register
ldr r0, [r0] //Load the contents of that address
//Now let's do something with that number...
```

If you check, for example, pushbuttons 0 and 2, that'll give you 5 in `r0`. Will that do?

The memory address that the button state can be read from is helpfully written in the panel header of CPUlator on the right. The switches panel corresponds to the word at 0xFF200040. I'm not sure what's at 0xFF200100. On a physical device, pushbuttons and switches are probably distinct, but in the CPUlator, I can't see any difference. Use the input source that you like better.

There's also a keyboard panel in the devices, but the processing of that would be more involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried getting input from keyboard panel. But as you mentioned, it makes more sense to use SW. But when we get the inputs from the user as binary, this wouldn't be user-friendly. How can I get input decimally using SW? So if the user presses 1 then 2, the input must be the number 12.

Comment: That's somewhat problematic. How will the program know that the user is done providing a digit and the program can read it? Imagine they want to input 11. So they check 1. The program reads it. Then what?

Comment: The user must enter the input within a certain time interval. I can use a timer for this.

Comment: To me, that's not very user friendly either :) But it's your project. Also, you would still need a way to indicate the end of input, an ENTER key of some kind. Anyway, did I answer the question?

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much again :)

Comment: We say thanks around here by accepting and/or upvoting the answer :)